# PHP PDO Update: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this problem came multiple times, but i cannot find the mistake in my code. In my update-branch every $stmt->bindValue(...) returns TRUE, but i catch the pdo exception

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Inserting a new entry works fine.

In my mysql-database the structure of table 'system' is:

```
id -> int(11), primary key
computer_name -> varchar(255)
cpu_speed -> int(11)
ram_size -> int(11)
mac_address -> varchar(255)
operating_system -> varchar(255)
```

My error-throwing code:

```
// Search for mac_address.
// If an entry with the same MAC exists update the entry.
// Else, create a new entry
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM system WHERE mac_address=:mac");
$stmt->bindValue(":mac", $mac_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// If no rows are returned, no entry exists => create a new one
if(empty($rows))
{  
  // Prepare statement
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO
       system(`computer_name`,`cpu_speed`,`ram_size`,`mac_address`, `operating_system`)
       VALUES(:computer_name, :cpu_speed, :ram_size, :mac_address, :operating_system)");
  $stmt->bindValue(":computer_name", $computer_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(":cpu_speed", $cpu_speed, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(":ram_size", $ram_size, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(":mac_address", $mac_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(":operating_system", $operating_system, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
else  // Update existing entry
{
  //computer_name   cpu_speed   ram_size    mac_address     operating_system 
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE system
      SET computer_name=:computer_name,
          cpu_speed=:cpu_speed,
          ram_size=:ram_size,
          operating_system=:operating_sytem,
          mac_address=:mac_address_in
       WHERE mac_address=:mac_address_query");
  echo$stmt->bindValue(":computer_name", $computer_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  echo$stmt->bindValue(":cpu_speed", $cpu_speed, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  echo$stmt->bindValue(":ram_size", $ram_size, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  echo$stmt->bindValue(":mac_address_in", $mac_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  echo$stmt->bindValue(":operating_system", $operating_system, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  echo$stmt->bindValue(":mac_address_query", $mac_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

// Execute the command
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Why don't you do it in a single query with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: Why are you setting `mac_address` to the value it already has?

Comment: Comment out all queries but one to find out which one of the three throws the error.

Comment: @GentiSaliu He says he knows which one is causing the error, it's the `UPDATE`.

Comment: Is this a verbatim copy of the code? There's probably a typo, and if you re-entered it here you may have corrected it in the process.

Comment: @Barmar Didn't see that.

Comment: ...................................ops

Comment: ":mac_address_query" is missing ;) see SET ...  _Invalid parameter number_

Comment: @Barmar: im quite new to mysql, so i did not check if mysql could do it for me. Also i did add the key (mac_address), because i wasnt sure if that maybe would have fixed the problem. But thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

This mean that you have a parameter that is not defined. It's seams that you have error here `operating_system=:operating_sytem,` may be it should be `operating_system=:operating_system,` . This make one missing parameter because it is not set here because you have misspelled a word. Please try to check every word in you `prepare` statement and the corresponding `bindValue`.

Comment: Another one of those "sitting too long in front of the computer on your own code"-typo-thing. Thx :)

Comment: @Incubbus Not just your own code, I didn't see it, either, and I'm usually pretty good at noticing these. But I was right when I said it was probably a typo somewhere.